# Images inside absolute positioned elements

Tags: css

I stumbled across a solution to a problem I was having with a website layout but wasn't sure if it was standard CSS practice or not. I've tested it on multiple platforms and browsers and it seems to be widely supported.

You can see what I'm talking about on [this page](https://pressmaximum.com/customify/site-library/?builder=elementor&demo=customify-2018).
The website linked to isn't my website but uses the same theme. I'm unable to post a link to my website as I'm working on it in a local environment.

The featured images are inside an element with `position: absolute` and the images themselves are set to `width: 100%` and `object-fit: cover`, and are unpositioned (i.e., static positioning).

The problem was I'm using product images and the `object-fit: cover` style setting was causing the images to get cut off.

The solution was to simply change the `object-fit: cover` setting to `object-fit: contain` which I understand is the default setting. This also centered the image even though the width of the images is less than the containing element.

Comment: I'm unclear on what the question is here. Please specify.

Comment: @El-Mo, I was just curious about the behavior of images inside absolutely positioned elements. Centering an image usually requires the use of `margin: 0 auto`.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because, when you use `background-size: cover;` it expands the image to cover the width of the `div` or element. In your case, image is being positioned `center center` that is why you have some top and bottom portion not visible. The only way I see to make this work is to increase the size of the element respectively with image or else resize the image to fit to the div.

If you want to check how it works. you can do this.

- inspect element
- change `background-size: cover` to `contain`
- add css property `height: 962px`;

However, it is not a good idea.

I would suggest the keep it the way you have it now and adjust the `background-position:` if you want particular area of the image to be covered. or use the image that fit that div.

Also, the height of the div is being controlled with the content inside so make sure you have control on those content too. Easy way is to set `min-height` for the parent div with background image.

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clearer that the website linked to in my original post isn't my website, it just uses the same theme. I'm unable to post a link to the actual website I'm working on as it's not currently online. I've updated my original post accordingly.